# What's the best method to list all active NICs and IP addresses in a vSphere cluster?

Tags: networking, command-line-interface, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

I have ESXi 5.1 with many hosts in a cluster. I would like to generate a list of active NICs and thier IP addresses. Whats the easiest tool to generate such a list?

*I am not looking for the Virtual Hardware, only the Physical network hardware.

Comment: Can you provide an example of why you'd need this information or what you would *do* with it?

Comment: I would like to document some of my infrastructure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use VMware vSphere PowerCLI.

It contains snapins of cmdlets based on Microsoft PowerShell for automating vSphere administration.

It can be downloaded from here https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=PCLI550&productId=353

Below a sample powershell script i wrote to retrieve infos you want.

Main points are :

- `Get-VMHost` with `-Location` parameter to query a specific cluster
  (in case you have more than one and that you want to limit the query to just one, that is my case)
- `Get-VMHostNetworkAdapter` with `-Physical` parameter to get only
  physical NICs.

---

```
$myVCenter = "vcenter.dom"     #fqdn or ip of the VCenter Server
$myClusterName = "PROD"        #Name of the ESXi cluster
$user = "username"
$pass = "password"

Connect-VIServer "$myVCenter" -User $user -Password "$pass"

$myvmhosts = Get-VMHost -Location $myClusterName | select Name
foreach($myvmhost in $myvmhosts)
{
  Get-VMHostNetworkAdapter -Physical -VMHost $myvmhost.Name | select VMhost, Name, Mac, IP | format-table -autosize  | Out-String
}
```

Will produce this output :

```
VMHost       Name    Mac                 IP
------       ----    ---                 --
esxsrv1      vmnic0  d4:ae:52:9e:7f:ad
esxsrv1      vmnic1  d4:ae:52:9e:7f:af
esxsrv1      vmnic2  d4:ae:52:9e:7f:b1
esxsrv1      vmnic3  d4:ae:52:9e:7f:b3
esxsrv1      vmnic4  00:10:18:e4:80:24
esxsrv1      vmnic5  00:10:18:e4:80:25
esxsrv1      vmnic6  00:10:18:dc:12:e0
esxsrv1      vmnic7  00:10:18:dc:12:e2

VMHost       Name    Mac                 IP
------       ----    ---                 --
esxsrv2      vmnic0  d4:ae:52:98:29:6e
esxsrv2      vmnic1  d4:ae:52:98:29:70
esxsrv2      vmnic2  d4:ae:52:98:29:72
esxsrv2      vmnic3  d4:ae:52:98:29:74
esxsrv2      vmnic4  00:10:18:e4:86:6e
esxsrv2      vmnic5  00:10:18:e4:86:6f
esxsrv2      vmnic6  00:10:18:dc:20:20
esxsrv2      vmnic7  00:10:18:dc:20:22
```

And so on for each ESXi server in the cluster...

In my VMWare architecture i don'y have IP on physical NICs, but if you have ones they will be displayed.

Another usefull tool is [RVTools](http://www.robware.net/). No need to write scripts. Install the tool, launch it and login, and you will have all infos, with filters and export possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Load up PowerCLI,

Connect to your Vcenter server.

```
Connect-VIServer <servername>
```

Then run

```
Get-VMHostNetworkAdapter
```

and a list of all nics and thier IP address are listed.

To export to a CSV

```
Get-VMHostAdapter | Export-Csv C:\list.csv
```